# Cannot find a certificate under location CurrentUser\CA

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a monitoring script in place to locate certificates that are about to expire. The monitoring service prompted us that there is an upcoming certificate that is about to expire and the path is

```
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\CA"
```

I tried to search for the certificate by opening `certmgr.msc` searched for the certificate and I cannot find it. Even running a powershell query of the Thumbprint of the certificate does not show the `CurretUser\CA` location. Can someone share a powershell command to show the certificate inside `CurrentUser\CA` directory?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Path 'cert:\CurrentUser\CA\'`…

Comment: Remember that CurrentUser is for, well, the current user.  So if your monitoring (or your current user) is a different user than the service that uses the certificate, you don't have the same CurrentUser contents.